# Rails 5 with Redis pubsub - after a while broadcast messages are not transmitted to clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm facing a weird issue. I have created an ActionCable controller to allow simplistic chat rooms.
When everything works, log messages show the `transmitting` message upon calling broadcast_to.

```
2017-03-05T10:29:21.624294+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T10:29:21.624222 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c] Registered connection (abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c)
2017-03-05T10:29:21.811899+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T10:29:21.811815 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c] ChatChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
2017-03-05T10:29:21.812216+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T10:29:21.812170 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c] ChatChannel is streaming from chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca
2017-03-05T10:29:22.204456+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T10:29:22.204364 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c] ChatChannel#some_event
2017-03-05T10:29:22.204555+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T10:29:22.204497 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca: {:type=>"some_event", :user=>"abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c"}
2017-03-05T10:29:22.207224+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T10:29:22.207164 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c] ChatChannel transmitting {"type"=>"some_event", "user"=>"abfcd3d23b1f4b895ce06cad5df51b8c"} (via streamed from chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca)
```

However when things stop working, the `transmitting` log message just stops showing

```
2017-03-05T09:29:20.534234+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T09:29:20.534167 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [b41c709c21deb8a2e9ae5f27b38d04b3] Registered connection (b41c709c21deb8a2e9ae5f27b38d04b3)
2017-03-05T09:29:20.747209+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T09:29:20.747112 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [b41c709c21deb8a2e9ae5f27b38d04b3] ChatChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
2017-03-05T09:29:20.747612+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T09:29:20.747562 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [b41c709c21deb8a2e9ae5f27b38d04b3] ChatChannel is streaming from chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca
2017-03-05T09:29:20.934563+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T09:29:20.934473 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [b41c709c21deb8a2e9ae5f27b38d04b3] ChatChannel#some_event
2017-03-05T09:29:20.934684+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-05T09:29:20.934626 #4]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [b41c709c21deb8a2e9ae5f27b38d04b3] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca: {:type=>"some_event", :user=>"b41c709c21deb8a2e9ae5f27b38d04b3"}
```

This is deployed on Heroku with Redis. When things stop working, doing `heroku restart` will fix everything and make things work again.

**small update**
When trying to do `Redis.new.pubsub("numsub", "chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca")` when everything is working I get:

```
=> ["chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca", 1]
```

when things stop working

```
=> ["chat:room_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca", 0]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So I think I have an answer.
It seems like the database connection has reached its limit:
<pre>
2017-03-05T11:37:14+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS_URL sample#num_connections_over_limit=1 message=Database connections over limit. Please upgrade your database plan.
</pre>

What I'm still not sure, is why am I not seeing any exception thrown or error

Comment: Also seems like this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810396/rails-puma-running-out-of-redis-connections
I'm trying to switch to Redis Cloud and see if it helps